# Remote Desktop Modifier Key Translation

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm connecting to Windows 11 Pro from a Mac. I'm a bit confused how Remote Desktop translates keystrokes. In particular, it seems that pressing the Mac Command key translates into the Windows key but so does the Option key. As a result, I have not found a way of sending the Alt keystrokes.

How do I send an Alt keystroke, like Alt-W?
Is this behavior documented or modifiable?
(Also, the Globe key seems to be ignored, but that doesn't surprise me.)